# Read stdout of a redis-cli subscribe and run bash command on message

Tags: bash, redis, systemd, etcd

I would like a bash script that reads the stdout of a `redis-cli` subscribe and does something when a message is received, along with the message value.

The subscribe can be passed in as an arg to `redis-cli` like so

```
redis-cli --raw subscribe foo
```

but then I need to pipe that stdout to something so I can parse the messages. I thought about using a `while read line; do` loop but a single redis message takes up 3 lines.

**update**

My endgame is to announce a new redis master by setting a key on etcd. This should be achievable by subscribing to the `switch-master` channel on a redis sentinel. [1] The value of that message should be something along the lines of `<master name> <oldip> <oldport> <newip> <newport>` and I would like to set that `newip` as a value on etcd.

The command I would like to run when that message is received is `etcdctl set /redis/master $NEWIP`

[1] http://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Comment: Can you give an example of a full message you're looking for and what the contents of `$MESSAGE` should be?

Comment: @zerodiff I've updated my question. Any help you can give, would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, piping the `stdout` doesn't seem to work with the `subscribe` command, but works fine with `get`

Comment: I'm more looking for the message text you're trying to capture and the piece(s) of the message you want to use. This will help people (like me) who don't know `redis`, `systemd`, or `etcd` help you with what's essentially a `bash` and parsing problem... :)

Answer (score 2):

because redis-cli subscribe output is currently buffered (https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2074) this isn't currently possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a tricky way: `expect`, save this in an executable file `redis-listen.expect`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn redis-cli psubscribe YOUR_CHANNEL_PATTERN*
expect
```

and now you can listen to redis:

```
./redis-listen.expect | grep channel
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable output buffering and read whole lines:

```
stdbuf -oL redis-cli --raw SUBSCRIBE channel | while read RCMD; do
    read CHANNEL
    read MSG
    [[ $RCMD == message ]] && echo "$CHANNEL: $MSG"
done
```